# UITableViewCell selection over UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiresponder

I get stuck with my cell selection. I have custom cell with `UITextView` object embedded in. It is not editable, not scrollable, with user interaction enabled. And I can not select cell over this view.

I've tried the same thing but with `UITextField` object and selection works.

Any ideas how to make it work?

[This is the test project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21379266/CellSelectionOverTextView.zip). There is just one table view with one cell. There is one text view and one text field in this cell. You can select the cell over the text field and can not over the text view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off "User Interaction Enabled" on your text view and the selection will work fine (MainStoryboard.storyboard->Table View Controller->Table View->Table View Section->Custom Table View Cell->Text View).  Allowing user interaction on the text view is capturing the taps before the table view cell gets them. Since your text view isn't scrollable or editable, you don't want user interaction enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expound a bit on [John Stephen's answer (which is the best as far as I can tell)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263927/9636).

I've tried this by subclassing `UITextView` and overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder`:

```
@interface MyTextView : UITextView

@end

@implementation MyTextView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
  return NO;
}

@end
```

I've also set `editable`, `selectable`, and `scrollEnabled` to `NO`:

```
MyTextView *textView = [MyTextView new];
textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

None of these worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of [John's answer for Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263927/9636) for programmatic solution is:

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```